# How can I see the list of users that have commit privileges to a git repo?

Tags: github

For example, the repo for Bitcoin Core: https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin

Has a contributors list: https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/graphs/contributors but no special indication who has commit privileges.

There is also the "organization" list of "people": https://github.com/orgs/bitcoin/people but again no special indication or label on who has what permissions.

Comment: To a *git* repo? You don't. And, to a repo hosted on *github*? You also, do not. If you are a member of the organization that owns thje repo, you can (through a ton of click-click-click) see who has merge rights, but that's about it.

Comment: From a quick google, there's no [permission](https://help.github.com/en/github/getting-started-with-github/access-permissions-on-github) called "commit" but there is one for organizations called "[Write](https://help.github.com/en/github/setting-up-and-managing-organizations-and-teams/repository-permission-levels-for-an-organization)" and one for user accounts called "[Collaborator](https://help.github.com/en/github/setting-up-and-managing-your-github-user-account/inviting-collaborators-to-a-personal-repository)".

Comment: [*"Organization owners can view people’s access to a repository within an organization."*](https://help.github.com/en/github/setting-up-and-managing-organizations-and-teams/viewing-people-with-access-to-your-repository)

Answer (score 1):

I've wanted the same info before and spent some time looking for an answer to this question. Unfortunately, as mentioned by myself and others in the comments, there is no really good way to do this.

By itself,`git` is decentralized; there is no "master server" on which users could be given a higher level of rights over the distributed code base than others. So it doesn't make sense to talk about such things in terms of pure `git`. But that doesn't work very well for projects in the real world, so we use things like `Github` to sit on top of `git` and act as a centralized master.

So Github bolts on top of git and adds some additional functionality, which includes some features for user management and access control. Organizations own repositories. Organizations have members and administrators. Repositories can have collaborators. And both members of the oraganization that owns the repository, and collaborators, can be granted *read/write* access on the repo itself.

So then your question can be rephrased as "how can I see the list of people in the organization that owns a repo, and how can I see the read/write permissions they have on that repo? And, how can I see who is added as a collaborator?"

The best answer I have been able to find is basically:

be an administrator on that organization. Navigate to the members list, click on each member, and check which rights they are granted on the repo in question. Then go to the repo itself, and under *settings*, click *collaborators*, and see who is listed there. You now have a list of people with read/write access to the repo.